# How to store subList operation on an ArrayList in another ArrayList in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, arraylist, type-mismatch, sublist

I am using **Kotlin REPL** in **IntelliJ Idea**

I have an `ArrayList`.

```
val myArrayList: ArrayList<String?> = arrayListOf("pig", null, "cow", "chicken", "chicken", "duck", "turkey", "pig", null, null, "turkey", "pig")
```

the operation

```
myArrayList.subList(2, 3)
```

gives me the output:

```
res5: kotlin.collections.MutableList<kotlin.String?> = [cow]
```

But the operation

```
val myArraySubList: ArrayList<String?> = myArrayList.subList(2, 3)
```

gives me the error:

```
error: type mismatch: inferred type is MutableList<String?> but kotlin.collections.ArrayList<String?> /* = java.util.ArrayList<String?> */ was expected
val myArraySubList: ArrayList<String?> = myArrayList.subList(2, 3)
                                         ^
```

So, here how can I store the result of a `subList` operation on an `ArrayList` in another `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ArrayList(myArrayList.subList(2, 3))
```

using this constructor:

> ```
> <init>(elements: Collection<E>)
> ```
>
> [Creates an ArrayList filled from the elements collection.](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-list/-init-.html)

But consider whether you actually need it: using `ArrayList` explicitly instead of `MutableList` is very rarely useful.

Comment: I am extremely sorry for my typing mistake, I have edited my question

Comment: Ah, ok. Happily this doesn't affect the main part of the answer :) Also, the list is not nullable either (that would be `ArrayList<Something>?`), it's a list of nullable strings.

Comment: I mean able to store `null` as value in the `ArrayList`

Comment: Thank you for clearing my confusion, I have further modified the question to make it more meaningful :-)